# Append triangular symbols along polyline in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have a polyline that needs to have triangles placed along the inside of the line as shown in the sample picture below. I've searched through ArcMap's symbology set and thought I could just add a second line along the original with a symbology of triangle shapes along the new line but cannot find anything appropriate in the symbology set. Any thoughts?

[image: Polyline Symbology]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by adding a marker line symbol to your line symbol.In the symbol property editor add a layer to the line by pressing the 'plus' button in the layer window.
[image]

Once you have added the layer select 'Marker Line Symbol' from the 'Type' drop-down menu.

[image]

Now press the 'Symbol' button and select the 'Triangle 1' symbol and adjust the size to your liking. Then press the 'Edit Symbol' button and adjust the Y axis offset to be just above the dashed line in the preview pane.
[image]

Now select the 'Template' tab and adjust the interval to your liking and press 'OK' to exit the editor.
[image]

You should now have a line styled like the one shown above.
[image]